# How to fetch chat message from socialcast? (API returning status message)

Tags: javascript, vmware-tools

I am using socialcast API's for chat feature. Using APIs from [socialcast API docs](https://socialcast.github.io/socialcast/)

While fetching group message I am using following url :

```
https://domain-com.socialcast.com/api/groups/:groupID/messages.json
```

but it returning status message (Post from group) instead of chat message.

Here I want to fetch chat message from group, How can I do that? Thanks for any help.

Same thing while posting chat message, but there I am using :  message_type=chat in request body so it's deliver in chat section of group.

But not able to fetch chat message form group.

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the groupid?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
Yes, I am passing group id. (getting  message which is post in group, not chat). I want chat messages.

Comment: You mean the same way which the documentation says here right? - https://socialcast.github.io/socialcast/apidoc/groups/messages.html

Comment: Yes, correct. 
But in response you can see : 
"message_type": "status_message"

I want chat instead of status message

Comment: Did you check the `activity_url` attribute?

Comment: Yes checked that also, but it showing : ["domain | Socialcast - Page Not Found"] in response.